# rails store current user email in database on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a column in my database called 'email'. I want to store the current logged in user's email address into this column when they submit a specific form.

At first I thought I should write something in the html to grab the current user's email address and hide it in the form somewhere but I realized that was probably a bad idea since anyone would be able to modify the html to put any email address that they want in there.

So my question is, would I go about this in the controller? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: may I know why you need to save email in database, either you can use session or if you have user table with email then use that user id to save it in another table

Comment: I want to track where the requests are coming from. How would I go about either method

Comment: I assume you have a user table. So, In the other table instead of having email field you can add the user_id field, so you can easily save current logged in user and for using association it will be easy

Comment: I do have a user table. Can you please give me an example that I can use to build on?

Comment: are you using devise gem?

Comment: no but im open to it

Comment: thats not a problem. after login if you get a current user thats enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

`@request.email = current_user.email
 @request.save`

Comment: you can use this but the default association won't work b/w request and user

Comment: Doesn't need to be an association for how im building it. Im basically going to write an if statement that says if the db email value matches the current user's email then x

Comment: oh ok kool... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm naming that other model as Article(you can use yours)

Have a column called user_id instead of email in that table

```
 Class User
   has_many :articles
 end

 Class Article
   belongs_to :user
 end


 class ArticlesController
   def create
     @article = current_user.articles.new(article_params)
     @article.save
   end

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:field1, :field2)
  end

 end
```

If you do something like this then automatically user_id will be saved in that table.
So it will be easy for you to get all articles which is belonged to that user.

```
user = User.first
user.artciles # you will get all articles belonged to that user

article = Article.first
article.user # you will get user of that article
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think Im almost there, I'm getting an error now though that says `Unable to autoload constant User, expected /RailsProjects/PROJECT/app/models/user.rb to define it`

Comment: do you have model called user?

Comment: yes, here's the code I have in there `class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :requests
end`

Comment: okay. I assume file name is user.rb and in the respective path mentioned in the above error

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer above